# What's a good weapon/power build for Boss Battle?

Tags: kid-icarus-uprising

Usually I vary the weapon I'm taking into a level based on whether it's hallways or open, primarily melee or sky, etc., and the kinds of enemies in it.

For the Boss Battle mode, though, I only get to pick one weapon to take on all the bosses. I'm pretty sure clubs are out, but what features should I be prioritizing? Damage, range, autododge and defense, melee ability, status effects, or something else entirely?

Likewise, what powers should I be bringing with me? Heals seem like a no-brainer, but what else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the weapon type, I would go with something that has good speed and range, so you don't need to risk being too close to the boss. I use palms mostly, and I have a Pudgy Palm at the moment, which has six stars in Range. Bosses aren't too affected by paralysis or freezing, but poison and fire damage is good if the weapon has it.

For powers, you would obviously want to bring in either Health Recovery or Crisis Recovery. Mega Lazer is good for the bosses that stay put and are slow, but I usually go with Health Recovery, Transparency, and Tirelessness. Being invisible will help you out immensely when you are in a tight spot.

Comment: I cleaned up Boss Battle Easy in under 17 minutes with a Laser Staff with extended range, speed +1, backwards dash cont. fire bonus. Every battle was just backwards dashing and firing. I didn't even need the health recoveries I brought.